# amCharts disabling animations

Tags: javascript, animation, amcharts

I am using amCharts to make a few graphs, but since the amount of data in said graphs is so large, the animation lags and consumes a lot of processing power, which isn't necessary.

I was wondering if its possible to disable all animations in an amCharts serial chart, and if so, how?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In amCharts serial charts animation is not enabled by default. If it is on for you, there is probably a line in your chart config which sets [`startDuration`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#startDuration) property. Just remove it, or set it to zero to disable all animations.

Comment: oh, my bad. I didn't notice that line when I used the template at the very beginning, and I kept trying to set startDuration to 0 at the top, and it had been getting reset the entire time at a later line. Whoops :) thanks

Comment: I simply update the JSON key with `startDuration: 0` and it did the magic. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated)` line from your code.

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/animations/#Using_Animated_theme